# Angular SSR flickering on animated elements

Tags: angular, seo, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular 7 site with several animations. Most of them start applying `opacity: 0` to the element and end with full `opacity:1`. All works fine. The small trouble appears when SSR comes into play.

For some reason the very first time I load the website I have the application flickering like loading twice, but it's not even that. It looks like the animations don't get applied when they are prerendered so that for a moment you see all the content as it was displayed then the transition to the browser state makes all go away and the animations start getting applied as usual.

If I navigate to any other route (even if it is lazy loaded or not) it works fine. As I say, it ONLY happens on the first load of the first page of the Angular site.

I have tried many things including `initialNavigation : 'enabled'` as is said here https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/439#issuecomment-331549488 , I have tried `preboot` (https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/439#issuecomment-331549488) and I have tried the TransferState from the server to the browser (note that the issues I have with are static code and no HTTP calls are involved). None of them work.

The only thing I'm trying is to apply a `'d-none' (display: none)` class if `isPlatformBrowser` is false however I do think a) it seems a hack and b) I may get bad scoring in SEO for that being classified as hidden content.

Have you guys come across this and know how to deal with animations and SSR in Angular 6+?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't seen a solution to this either, and like you, have been applying a class with opacity: 0 on any animated elements, which is then removed on isPlatformBrowser. Definitely feels hacky.

Comment: I just can’t believe that hasn’t been an impact on many sites and therefore the issue has been addressed appropriately. Either that or I haven’t found the right piece of code to get around it

Comment: Have you tried using state() in your animations? I haven't given that a go, mostly because for me, the animations that happen right after load have been using query(), and unfortunately you can't mix query with state. It may very well be that SSR simply ignored all animations on the server and only applies them on the transition to browser. In which case even state wouldn't help.

Comment: I have state and they didn’t work unfortunately